# Components and aggregations in SAPUI5

Tags: components, sapui5, aggregation, setter

I nee a Tree as an aggregation in my project. I find something about, how to acces them. But I got still a problem ... Everytime I want to call the method `setTitle` of the Tree I got an Exception: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setTitle' of null`

My code looks like this:

```
sap.ui.core.UIComponent.extend("ui5_i.myComponent.Component", {

metadata : {
    includes: ["../../resources/css/org-struct.css"],
    properties : {
        treeTitle: "string",
        searchPlaceholder: "String",
        showId: { type:"boolean", defaultValue: true },
        data: "object",
        height :"string",
        width: "string"
    },
    aggregations: { 
        _Tree : {type:'sap.ui.commons.Tree', multiple: false}
    }
},

createContent: function(){
        console.log("createContent!");
        this.set_Tree(new sap.ui.commons.Tree());
        ....
        .... here comes the rest of the view
}
```

And my setter Method:

```
ui5_i.myComponent.Component.prototype.setTreeTitle = function(sTitle) {
if(typeof(sTitle) === "string" && sTitle != undefined && sTitle !=null){
     this.setProperty("treeTitle", sTitle);
     this.get_Tree().setTitle(sTitle);
     return this;
}else{
    throw("Property 'treeTitle' is not of type 'string' or 'undefined'!");
}
```

I don't understand the error, because the content is created, so the tree can't be `null`, I even see the Tree when I comment the setter method, so I normally can call the setTitle method ...
Anyone an idea what's going wrong?

EDIT: I realised, that my _Tree is everytime null, but I used the setter to initialize it ... I also changed it and put the init of the tree into my init() method, but than I want to add the tree to the View and get an error like this: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addDelegate' of null`
Here is the whole code:

```
    jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.core.UIComponent");
jQuery.sap.require("sap.ui.commons.Tree");
jQuery.sap.declare("ui5_i.myComponent.Component");

sap.ui.core.UIComponent.extend("ui5_i.myComponent.Component", {

    metadata : {
        includes: ["../../resources/css/org-struct.css"],
        properties : {
            treeTitle: "string",
            searchPlaceholder: "String",
            showId: { type:"boolean", defaultValue: true },
            data: "object",
            height :"string",
            width: "string"
        },
    aggregations: { 
        _oTree : {type:'sap.ui.commons.Tree', multiple:false }
    }
    },

    init : function ( ){
        sap.ui.core.UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments );
        var oSearchSettings = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel({
            "partially_search": "true",
            "case_sensitive": "true",
            "searchedText": "",
            "aSearchResults" : [],
            "indexOfSearchResults": "0"
        });
        sap.ui.getCore().setModel("settings", oSearchSettings);
        this.set_oTree(new sap.ui.commons.Tree());
    },



    createContent: function(){
        var oResponsiveLayout = new sap.ui.layout.form.ResponsiveGridLayout({columnsL: 3,columnsM: 2, columnS: 1});
        var oFormLayout = new sap.ui.layout.form.Form({
            width: this.getProperty("width"),
            height: this.getProperty("height"),
            layout: oResponsiveLayout,
            formContainers: [ new sap.ui.layout.form.FormContainer({
                                formElements: [new sap.ui.layout.form.FormElement({
                                                   fields: [ this.oSearchField =  new sap.ui.commons.SearchField({
                                                    placeholder : "Suchtext / ID",
                                                    search: this._onSearchRequest,
                                                    layoutData: new sap.ui.layout.GridData({span: "XL8 L8 M8 S8"})
                                                }), this.oArrowUp = new sap.ui.commons.Button({
                                                    width: "40px",
                                                    icon: "resources/images/arrow_up.png",
                                                    layoutData: new sap.ui.layout.GridData({span: "XL1 L1 M1 S1"})
                                                }), this.oArrowDown = new sap.ui.commons.Button({
                                                    width: "40px",
                                                    icon: "resources/images/arrow_down.png",
                                                    layoutData: new sap.ui.layout.GridData({span: "XL1 L1 M1 S1"})
                                                }),
                                                this.oSettingsMenuButton = new sap.ui.commons.MenuButton({
                                                    height: "80%",
                                                    width: "50px",
                                                    icon: "resources/images/settings.png", 
                                                    lite: true,
                                                    layoutData: new sap.ui.layout.GridData({span: "XL2 L2 M2 S2"}),
                                                    menu: new sap.ui.unified.Menu({
                                                        items: [ new sap.ui.unified.MenuItem({
                                                            text: "ID",
                                                            submenu: new sap.ui.unified.Menu({
                                                                items: [ this.oIdMenuButton = new sap.ui.unified.MenuItem({
                                                                    text: "IDs anzeigen/ausblenden",
                                                                    icon: "resources/images/check.png",
                                                                    select: this._onShowHideIdRequest
                                                                })]
                                                            })
                                                        }), new sap.ui.unified.MenuItem({
                                                            text: "Suche",
                                                            submenu: new sap.ui.unified.Menu({
                                                                items: [ new sap.ui.unified.MenuItem({
                                                                    text: "Teilsuche aktivieren/deaktivieren",
                                                                    icon: "resources/images/check.png",
                                                                    select: this._onPartiallySearchRequest
                                                                }), new sap.ui.unified.MenuItem({
                                                                    text: "Groß- und Kleinschreibung beachten/ignorieren",
                                                                    icon: "resources/images/check.png",
                                                                    select: this._onCaseSensitiveRequest
                                                                })]
                                                            })
                                                        })] 
                                                    })
                                                }) ]
                                               }),new sap.ui.layout.form.FormElement({
                                                   fields: [ this.get_oTree()]
                                               })]
                            })]
        });
        return oFormLayout;
    },

    _bindData : function(){
        var oJsonModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(this.getProperty("data"));
        this.getAggregation('_oTree').setModel(oJsonModel,"org_structJSON");
        this._loadNodes();
    },

    _loadNodes: function(){
        var rootPath = this._getRootPath();
        var aParentID = [];
        for(key in rootPath){
            var parentID = rootPath[key].parent;
            if(aParentID.indexOf(parentID) < 0){
                aParentID.push(parentID);
                this._loadChildNodes(parentID);
            }

        }
    },

    _getRootPath : function() {
        var oJSON = this.oTree.getModel("org_structJSON");
        return oJSON.getProperty("/ORG_UNITS");
    },

    _loadChildNodes : function(parentID) {
        var rootPath = this._getRootPath();
        if(parentID === ""){
            for(key in rootPath){
                var node = rootPath[key];
                if(node.parent === parentID){
                    var rootNode = this._createNode(node.id, node.short_text);
                    this.getAggregation(_oTree).addNode(rootNode);
                }
            }
        }else{
            var aNodes = this.oTree.findAggregatedObjects(true);
            for(var index = 0; index < aNodes.length; index++){
                var nodeID = aNodes[index].getId();
                if(nodeID.slice(1,nodeID.length) === parentID){
                    for(key in rootPath){
                        if(rootPath[key].parent === parentID){
                            var oChildNode = this._createNode(rootPath[key].id, rootPath[key].short_text);
                            aNodes[index].addNode(oChildNode);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

    _createNode : function(id, short_text) {
        var oNode = new sap.ui.commons.TreeNode({
            id : "_" + id,
            icon : "resources/images/organisation_unit.gif",
            expanded: false
        });
        if(window.showId){
            oNode.setText(short_text + " (" + id + ")");
        }else{
            oNode.setText(short_text)
        }
        return oNode;
    },

    _onSearchRequest : function(oControlEvent) {

    },

    _onShowHideIdRequest : function(){

    },

    _onPartiallySearchRequest : function(){

    },

    _onCaseSensitiveRequest : function(){

    }


});


ui5_i.myComponent.Component.prototype.setTreeTitle = function(sTitle) {
    if(typeof(sTitle) === "string" && sTitle != undefined && sTitle !=null){
         this.setProperty("treeTitle", sTitle);
         this.get_oTree().setTitle(sTitle);
         return this;
    }else{
        throw("Property 'treeTitle' is not of type 'string' or 'undefined'!");
    }
},

ui5_i.myComponent.Component.prototype.setData = function(oData) {
    if(typeof(oData) === "object" && oData != undefined && oData !=null){
            this.setProperty("data", oData);
            this._bindData();
            return this;
    }else{
        throw("Property 'data' is not of type 'object' or undefined!");
    }
},

ui5_i.myComponent.Component.prototype.setSearchPlaceholder = function(sText) {
    if(typeof(sText) === "string" && sText != undefined && sText !=null){
        this.setProperty("searchPlaceholder", sText);
        this.oSearchField.setPlaceholder(sText);
        return this;
    }else{
        throw("Property 'searchPlaceholder' is not of type 'string' or 'undefined!'");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does your edit mean that you have found your answer? If so, please consider posting it as an actual answer to the question.

Comment: No, I don't have a solution

Comment: In your code it seem like `get_Tree` returns null, can you include that method in your question?

Comment: I added the whole code above ;)

Answer (score 0):

`createContent()` is called by [UIComponent.init()](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.core/src/sap/ui/core/UIComponent.js#L259). That is what you are calling with `sap.ui.core.UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments );`.

So at the time your `createContent()` runs you have not yet initialized the Tree. Move the last line of your `init()` function to the top in that function.

---

Edit: I can see an additional problem with your code:

The [documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.base.ManagedObject.html) states the following about aggregations:

> Managed aggregations can store one or more references to other ManagedObjects. They are a mean to control the lifecycle of the aggregated objects: one ManagedObject can be aggregated by at most one parent ManagedObject at any time.

So when you are adding the Tree to your Form in  `createContent()` it will get automaticaly removed from your Components aggregation.

I'm not shure what you are trying to acomplish, but perhaps you have to think about a getMethod that looks up the Tree by ID or you could use an association instead of a aggregation.

Comment: I've found an other problem and updated my answer. Can you say more about what you need that aggregation for?

Comment: Ok, thank you :) I thought that I should use aggregations when I need a tree in my component. But know I set the tree as a normal object (this.tree) and use the tree right know in this way.

Comment: Yes, you should instantiate the tree in `createContent()` together with the other Controls and store a reference in a field if you need it. Keep it simple:)